# How long it takes for new images to get indexed by Google in general? (now i'm on a Squarespace site if it makes any difference)

Tags: google-search-console, web-crawlers, google-index, google-image-search, image-search

i'm wondering, if there is some benchmark out there on this info? I see [many sources](https://support.google.com/webmasters/forum/AAAA2Jdx3sUaaT9SBrE6l4/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fwebmasters%2FaaT9SBrE6l4) say

> it's about 4 days to 4 weeks to get new sites indexed

But it's about general web crawling and not specifically about the *image search*.

**With a Squarespace website I just passed ~4 weeks without a single new image get indexed. I'm wondering is it normal?**

- site is google console verified
- sitemap added, it works, google reads it frequently
- web pages are getting indexed, but 0 images yet

Bonus question: by the way, why I can't find the image crawling/indexing section in g console? It's still not implemented to the "*new experience*"?

I'm curious about some 'live', recent data about this from you, webmaster fellas.
Thank you.

**Update:**

Goolge started to crawl my new images after about 25-28 days. (Small, niche website. It's html webpages got crawled early, in abt 2-3 weeks.

Comment: How are you testing to see if images are indexed?   The search console inspection tool is known to be broken for images URLs.  It always shows they are blocked by robots.txt even if they are not and are actually indexed.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the only way i use now is the good-old typing "site:mywebsite.com" into google search bar and chose the 'Images' search option that shows me the 'real world' (all the currently indexed images of the given domain or url), but then i still can't see any info about possible errors, blocks, failures from google crawlers side. I really hope, they will improve image search management in the newer Google Console very soon.

Comment: For what it is worth, it seems that Google will pick up some photos quickly then stop for a while. It appears to take a long time to get images indexed. Google has always been slow, from my experience anyway, to index images. How long will it take? I am sure no-one can say with any certainty. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

From my experience you cannot tell how long it will take for your images to be shown in Google Image search. Factors that can affect the speed are:

1. How much content your site has.
2. How much of a niche your site is.
3. How good is your site in terms of end user value.
4. How good is your site in terms of SEO.
5. How popular your site is. If it's brand new site then time will extend based on this.

The key here is patience. Also, make sure everything is correct. Use the guideline in the link you provided to make sure of that.

Bonus tip: Use `inurl:"www.example.com"` in the search box to filter results to show only your site's images.

Bonus Answer: Image crawling/indexing isn't available in the new Search Console.

Comment: To add to an excellent answer, It can take months to a year. In the mean time, ensure there are no html or css errors, it is mobile friendly and try to develop backlinks.